# Is there a Rails convention for how to structure nested models using FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, factory-bot

There is a part of BDD that I am really confused about. I have all kinds of different request specs to test. With the following structure:

- User has_many Products
- Product has_many PriceLevels
- PriceLevel has_many Prices

I am confused about how to go about setting up factories using FactoryGirl. I am familiar with the concept of associations and traits. I am familiar with the concepts of `build` and `create`. But I am unsure in what situations to use these.

The best way I can communicate what I am confused about is to give some examples.

- I have a request spec to test `User` registration. I don't use a factory here for obvious reasons. This I understand.
- I have a request spec to test a `User` creating new `Products`. I `create` a user factory. I assume I need to use `create` instead of `build` here, because the CRUD methods in the `ProductsController` do an AR `find` on the id that is passed via the URL. Correct me if I'm wrong here.
- I have a request spec to test adding different `PriceLevels` for a `Product`. Here I am using two factories: `User` and `Product`.
- I have a request spec to test adding different `Prices` for a `User`'s `Product`'s `PriceLevel`. Now I'm up to 3 factories: `User`, `Product`, `PriceLevel`.

Now what if `Price` has a `has_and_belongs_to_many` with something like `Currency`? The factories are getting out of hand.

I'd say by the time I get to `PriceLevel` then I want a single factory that will let me create the whole structure at once. And yet, I don't want to create whole structure ***every single time***. Plus, these factories can be created from the bottom up or the top down.

Which way is better, bottom up or top down? Can I create DRY code that gives me options on a single factory or creating the whole shebang at once? Can I wrap `after(:create)` blocks within traits? Would I ever use `build` vs `create` in request specs?

Thanks very much for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `build` vs `create` in Request specs:

I commonly use `build` or `build_stubbed` in controller specs by stubbing `Model.find` to return the built instances. However, mocking in general should be avoided in Feature or Request specs, so go ahead and`create` things here.

Now as for the main problem:

This sounds like a perfect case for traits. In general, base factories should have only the attributes required to make a valid model. Traits can then be used to make handy "aliases" for common or verbose scenarios.

You can use `before(:create)` to build and assign related models. Rails will handle saving everything together when FG eventually calls `save`/`create` internally.

Example:

```
factory :user do
  # ...

  trait :with_products do
    before(:create) do |user|
      user.products = build_list(:product, 3)
    end
  end

  trait :with_priced_products do
    before(:create) do |user|
      user.products = build_list(:product, 3, :with_prices)
    end
  end
end

factory :product do
  # ...

  trait :with_prices do
    before(:create) do |product|
      product.prices = build_list(:price, 3)
    end
  end
end

factory :price
```

If you wanted to customize how many products/prices are added at build-time, you can just add `ignore`d attributes and use them via the 2-argument form of the before-hook.

```
ignore do
  number_of_products 3
end

before(:create) do |user, evaluator|
  user.products = build_list(product, evaluator.number_of_products)
end
```

If you wanted to be able to use these `with_` traits in `build` or `build_stubbed` scenarios, you're going to have to duplicate the relevant hooks using the correct strategy in each case. There's currently no easy way to say "add some relations using the same strategy as the model", though that's a wishlist item for myself too.